# tensorflow: object has no attribute 'matrix_inverse', how to verify it should be supported?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running the following code on a server with a gpu, using tensorflow-gpu version=1.2:

> matrix_b = tf.matrix_inverse(matrix_a)

When running the same code on my laptop (no gpu) with tensorflow version=1.8 it works.

As I see in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/matrix_inverse), this is implemented for the tensorflow version I am using, so it should be supported. yet I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'matrix_inverse'

so to my question - Can it be that the matrix_inverse() is not supported in tensorflow-gpu 1.2 but is supported in tensorflow 1.2?
and if so, where can I see the correct documentation?

Answer (score 3):

The answer may come a little late.

Use `tf.linalg.inv()` instead of `tf.matrix_inverse()`